# Knockout Validation Firing on Initial Load

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

We are currently working on a razor application using knockout 2.1. We have started using the knockout validation library.

The issue is that the ko validations are being fired on the initial load of the popup. What are we missing here - maybe on the initial load of the view, knockout thinks the view model has changed and therefore fires the validations? How can we determine which property on the view model has changed and is there a way to stop that explicitly?

Here is a simplified fiddle to show the issue - Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/1307/

Code snippet:

```
var LeaveEditViewModel = function() {

this.hours = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
this.hours.isModified(false); 
this.registerClick = function() {

this.hours()           

this.hours.isModified(false);
}; 

};

var leaveEditViewModel = new LeaveEditViewModel();

leaveEditViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(leaveEditViewModel);
ko.validation.configure({
registerExtenders: true,
messagesOnModified: true,
insertMessages: false,
parseInputAttributes: true,
messageTemplate: null,
grouping: {
deep: true
}
});
ko.applyBindings(leaveEditViewModel);
```

We are using the prop.IsModified(false); call too..

Any help will be appreciated guys

Thanks

Comment: leaveEditViewModel.errors.showAllMessages(false); to hide the error messages at initial and when you don't what to show messages.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found it was because I had a save function on my view model that was bound to the knockout click binding on my form like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click:app.viewModel.save()" />
```

The view model save function was checking isValid on my model causing the errors to show. This is what I wanted except when you bind in this way, the click binding invokes the function on page load.

I wrapped the view model save function in another function and the problem went away:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click:function(e,i){app.viewModel.save();}" />
```

I do not know if this is your exact situation since you did not post all of the code but, if not, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You don't need to wrap it in another function, just drop the parentheses: `data-bind="click:app.viewModel.save" />`